# NSUserDefaults set the default value of integer variable to empty

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I used NSUserDefaults to store an integer value. When I run the project there's a default value of 0 in it. How do I remove the 0 value? I just want it to be empty until the user put something in it.

Here is my code:

```
    - (IBAction)save:(id)sender{
     int port = [[portField text] integerValue];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     [defaults setInteger:port forKey:@"port"];
     [defaults synchronize];
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
     int port = [defaults integerForKey:@"port"];
     NSString *portString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)port];

     portField.text = portString;
     [super viewDidLoad];
    }
```

Comment: FYI - you might want to add a check in your `save:` method such that if the text field is empty you either delete any existing "port" value or you leave the current value as-is. As written you will end up writing `0` if the text field is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this line:

```
 int port = [defaults integerForKey:@"port"];
```

will always assign *some* value to `port`.

Also, this:

```
 NSString *portString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)port];
```

will always produce a non-empty string. There's no value you could pass for a `%lu` specifier that will produce an empty string.

So, what you want to do is ask for the *object* that's stored in the preferences, without converting it to a integer value:

```
id portObject = [defaults objectForKey:@"port"];
if (portObject)
{
    NSInteger port;
    if ([portObject respondsToSelector:@selector(integerValue)])
        port = [portObject integerValue];
    else
    {
        // portObject is some unexpected class of object, such as an array or dictionary. Take some appropriate action. Or:
        port = 0;
    }
    portField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)port];
}
else
{
    // There was no value either stored or registered for the key "port"
    portField.text = @"";
}
```

Note that for this to work, you must **not** have registered a default value for the "port" key using `-[NSUserDefaults registerDefaults:]`.

Comment: The port = 0 works when I enter a non integer value but when I leave it blank I still get the 0 value.

Comment: That's not a "default" value (which is what you asked about). That's a result of your `-save:` method having run on a previous occasion. That method doesn't check for the text field's `text` being either empty or `nil`. It converts it into an integer regardless, gets 0, and stores that 0 in the user defaults. You need to detect conditions under which you don't want to store a value and **not store a value** for that case. You may even want to remove any previously stored value using `-removeObjectForKey:`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, NSUserDefaults always return default values for primitive types when they are not exists.

If the default value is a valid value you use, I suggest to put a blank object or just NSString object to determine if the associated value is valid. e.g.

```
NSObject *objValid = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"integerIsValid"];
if(objValid != nil) {
    // User stored integer value exists.
    NSInteger i = [userDefaults integerForKey:@"SomeInteger"];
} else {
    // Have not saved integer value.
}
```

When user save the integer value, also save the associated object:

```
[userDefaults setObject:[[NSObject alloc]init] forKey:@"integerIsValid"];
[userDefaults setInteger:i forKey:@"SomeInteger"];
```

**UPDATE**

If your value range can transform to another value range by some rules, then you can do it another way.

All values are in range [0, 100) for example, you can store in range [1, 101) and retrieve the real value by subtracting 1.

Comment: Not quite true. It's not that `NSUserDefaults` returns default values when they don't exist. It's a matter of calling methods like `integerValue`, `floatValue`, `boolValue`, etc. on `nil` when the key doesn't exist. They all result in `0`. So this makes it appear like `NSUserDefaults` returns `0` for primitive types when the key has no value.

Comment: BTW - this isn't a good solution. There is no need to store a secondary value just to see if the desired value is valid or not.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes you are right, it's not the best way, I update answer to add another way.